# Square root of complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, branch-points

Question: Let the square root be computed using the branch $L_{\pi/2}$ of the logarithm. Where is
$(z^2-i)^\frac{1}{2}$ not analytic?

My solution:

The function is not analytic when $\sqrt{z^2-i}=yi, y \in \mathbb{R}/{\mathbb{R^-}}$ (along the non-negative imaginary axis). Hence, solving for the $z$ of the equation is sufficient.

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
        z^2-i &= -y^2\\
        z^2  &= -y^2+i\\
 z &= \pm \sqrt{\underbrace{-y^2+i}_\beta}\\
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

Now, let's convert $\beta$ to the form of $|\beta|e^{i\theta}$.

$\theta = \arctan{\frac{1}{-y^2}}$ and $|\beta| = y^4 + 1$.

Hence, $z = \pm\sqrt{\beta} = \pm\sqrt{(y^4 + 1)e^{i\arctan{\frac{1}{-y^2}}}}$

Now, my solution is going south since $-y^2$ became a denominator and can be $0$.

Can someone please point out where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think the domain of $y$ should be $R^+$ not including $0$ because it is not defined.